# OOP - Should a class define exactly how its printed?

Tags: oop

I'm new to OOP, so this question might be basic: Should a class define how it's printed?
I know classes define toString (or similar methods) that can return a representation of the class, but should a class which hold data have method which actually prints this data to stdout (e.g. including handling indentation, colors, etc.)?

On the one hand, it would seem like a break of abstraction, as the class doesn't know where it's running or is familiar with the console.
On the other hand, it seems reasonable that the class would know how to print itself, and also it allows for adding new classes without having to modify a seperate code part which knows how to print all these data classes.

What is correct from OOP perspective?

Comment: I think this is more of a programmers.stackexchange sort of question. But that said, it depends on the context. Imagine a debugger that used colorization to highlight important information. Even a simple data only class could provide hints as to how it should be colorized. It might not make sense for it to specify the specific colors though. Idiomatic C++ involves passing ostream objects to objects that they may render themselves, and that is just fine.

Comment: @AluanHaddad when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat thank you, but that reference is not explicit about what the user should do if they happen to pick the wrong site. Is it still cross-posting if they delete their original post on their own _before_ posting the would be duplicate?